# PLSQL: Assign array returned by one function into an array defined in another function

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I have two functions – func1 and func2. func1 selects some values from a table and assigns it to an array and returns this array. func2 calls func1. func2 uses the array returned by func1 to perform some operations. My question is: How to assign the array returned by func1 to an array in func2. Please find below the code snippets of func1 and func2.

```
function func1 (table1 varchar2, table2 varchar2) return j_list
  is
   type j_list is varray (10) of VARCHAR2(50);
   attr_list j_list := j_list(); 
   counter integer :=0;  
  begin   
for i in 
    (select  a.column_name from  all_tab_columns a) 

    LOOP 
      counter := counter + 1; 
      attr_list.extend; 
      attr_list(counter)  := i.column_name;
    END LOOP;
   return attr_list;
end func1;


function func2 (table1 varchar2, table2 varchar2) return varchar2
  is
   type new_j_list is varray (10) of VARCHAR2(50);
   new_attr_list j_list := j_list();
   new_attr_list.extend;
   new_attr_list() := func1 (table1, table2) /*does this assign the array                  
that is returned by func1 into the array new_attr_list ??? */
   jt varchar2(4000);
  begin  
  jt := /*some operations using the new_attr_list*/
  return jt;
end func2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code have some errors. You cannot use `j_list` without declaring it at first place. The scope of `j_list` has to be declared prior to use. See below how you can do it. Also method `extend` should be used in `begin` block not in `declaration` block.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE j_list IS VARRAY (10) OF VARCHAR2(50);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1 (    table1 VARCHAR2,
                                      table2 VARCHAR2
                                  ) 
RETURN j_list 
IS    
    attr_list   j_list := j_list ();
    counter     INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN ( SELECT a.column_name FROM all_tab_columns a) 
    LOOP
        counter := counter + 1;
        attr_list.extend;
        attr_list(counter) := i.column_name;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN attr_list;
END func1;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2 ( table1 VARCHAR2,
                                  table2 VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS
    new_attr_list   j_list := j_list ();
    jt              VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    new_attr_list.extend;
    new_attr_list:= func1(table1, table2 );

    jt := 'some operations using the new_attr_list';
    RETURN jt;
END func2;
```